# Elasticsearch/Filebeat _meta/fields.yml not loading into kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, kibana, metadata, filebeat

I'm assigned to a filebeat plugin of our product. I wrote a IngestPipeline and de default mapping is in various ways unfortunately so i wanted to change this with the _meta/fields.yml.
I configured the yml file accordingly to:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/7.8/filebeat-modules-devguide.html#_metafields_yml_2
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/current/event-fields-yml.html
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/82273

My yml file looks like this:

```
- key: pac
  title: "pac"
  description: Description missing
    pac Module
  fields:
    - name: pac.log
      type: group
      description: Description missing
      fields:
        - name: deo
          type: group
          description: Description missing
          fields:
            - name: duration
              type: long
              description: Duration of the deo
            - name: category
              type: keyword
              description: Category of the deo
            - name: owner
              type: keyword
              description: User of the deo
            - name: version
              type: float
              description: Version of the deo
            - name: name
              type: keyword
              description: Name of the deo
            - name: reference
              type: double
              description: Referencenumber of the deo
            - name: state
              type: keyword
              description: State of the deo
            - name: status
              type: keyword
              description: Status of the deo
            - name: trigger
              type: group
              description: Description missing
              fields:
                - name: category
                  type: keyword
                  description: Category of the deo-trigger
                - name: name
                  type: text
                  description: Name of the deo-trigger
                - name: path
                  type: text
                  description: Full-Text of the trigger properties
                - name: provider
                  type: keyword
                  description: Supplier of the deo-trigger
            - name: wiring
              type: group
              description: Description missing
              fields:
                - name: async
                  type: boolean
                  description: If deos wired asynchronously
                - name: deoId
                  type: keyword
                  description: Identification number of the deo
                - name: execute
                  type: boolean
                  description: If deo is executed or not
                - name: owner
                  type: keyword
                  description: User of the deo
                - name: shared
                  type: boolean
                  description: Deo was shared
                - name: stopOnError
                  type: boolean
                  description: If deo stopped on Error
        - name: do
          type: group
          description: Description missing
          fields:
            - name: name
              type: keyword
              description: Name of the do task
            - name: state
              type: group
              description: Description missing
              fields:
                - name: from
                  type: keyword
                  description: State from which the do task was used
                - name: to
                  type: keyword
                  description: State to which the do task was switched
        - name: esa
          type: group
          description: Description missing
          fields:
            - name: connection
              type: keyword
              description: Connection status of the ESA
            - name: name
              type: keyword
              description: Name of the ESA
            - name: state
              type: group
              description: Description missing
              fields:
                - name: from
                  type: keyword
                  description: State from which the ESA Connection was established
                - name: to
                  type: keyword
                  description: State to which the ESA Connection was established
        - name: monitor
          type: group
          description: Description missing
          fields:
            - name: heap
              type: group
              description: Description missing
              fields:
                - name: bytes
                  type: long
                  description: Used bytes of the heap
                - name: pct
                  type: float
                  description: Percentage of the maximum available bytes
            - name: heapgc
              type: group
              description: Description missing
              fields:
                - name: bytes
                  type: long
                  description: Used bytes of the heapgc
                - name: pct
                  type: float
                  description: Percentage of the maximum available bytes
        - name: service
          type: group
          description: Description missing
          fields:
            - name: class
              type: keyword
              description: Class of the service
            - name: duration
              type: long
              description: How long the service call took
            - name: name
              type: keyword
              description: Name of the service call
            - name: operation
              type: keyword
              description: Operation type of the service call
            - name: success
              type: boolean
              description: Was the service call successfull or not
        - name: system
          type: group
          description: Description missing
          fields:
            - name: category
              type: keyword
              description: Category of the System
            - name: priority
              type: keyword
              description: Priority of the System
            - name: monitor
              type: group
              description: Description missing
              fields:
                - name: cpu
                  type: group
                  description: Description missing
                  fields:
                    - name: pct
                      type: float
                      description: Percentage of the cpu usage
        - name: wiring
          type: text
          description: Description missing
        - name: meta
          type: text
          description: Description missing
        - name: tags
          type: keyword
          description: Description missing
        - name: timestamp
          type: date
          description: Description missing
        - name: level
          type: keyword
          description: Description missing
        - name: logger
          type: keyword
          description:  Description missing
```

I would like to have the field types as configured in the fields.yml file. But at first no mapping is available and if i start to send logs the mapping for my fields is created automatically with unfortunate types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yaml file works as it is in the description above. My Problem was that my collegue from whom i inherited the project didn't use the filebeat build script. So the uploaded fields.yml file wasn't extended by my fields. I reconfigured the fields.yaml path inside the filebeat.yml configuration file and now it works.